# Possible to write only in OpenCL?

Tags: cpu, opencl

Let say I've got a nice algorithm which I want to code to run on both CPUs and GPUs. I know I can [target x86 with OpenCL](http://www.acooke.org/cute/Developing0.html).

Should I prepare two versions of my code (for CPUs and GPUs) written one in OpenCL, the other in a traditional way? Or maybe I can just make one implementation in OpenCL, and run it with AMD's SDK on machines without proper GPU? What drawbacks does running OpenCL on CPU have, compared to an implementation in pure C?

(Note: I understand that I will need to write OpenCL initialization and input/output in traditional way. The question covers only the computational part of a program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try going down the path of writing it in just OpenCL.  That way you have one version of the code that runs on both CPU and GPU... in theory.

In practice, to get optimum performance you might want to tweak your code for the particular hardware you are targeting.  For example, x86 CPU might benefit from using vectors while NVidia GPU might not as much or at all (in fact even different versions of hardware from the same manufacturer could have different characteristics).

To target GPU, you'll likely need an OpenCL version of your algorithm anyway.  When tweaking for particular hardware, you can go down the path of using #define/#ifdef and rewrite or tweak only parts of the algorithm that need it.  This may work for your algorithm and save you duplicating a whole lot of code.

A disadvantage of OpenCL is that it is harder to use than just coding or using a C library.  If your library/algorithm is for somebody else and it is written in OpenCL, you are forcing them to include the OpenCL libraries and have an OpenCL runtime on their system.  It can also be harder to debug - no console printing (but there are extensions that support this) and I haven't got any experience with OpenCL debuggers but I doubt they are as good as traditional debuggers.

Comment: So: [1] OpenCL code will be slower than C code (but this is a CPU, it will be slower than GPU anyway), [2] more difficulty in integrating code (but I was going to use OpenCL anyway), [3] less mature tools like debuggers/profilers (but I was going to use OpenCL anyway).

Comment: @liori [1] C code may or may not be slower.  For example, it is easier to use vector instructions and threads from OpenCL than with straight C.  When running on CPU, technically anything written in OpenCL could be also written in C / assembly, but the OpenCL code might end up cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to the already given answer: You can write an OpenCL kernel and let it run on GPU and CPU using the drivers from AMD and Intel. Modern multicore CPUs support this. In that case you have one piece of code and can use it (almost) everywhere.

Disadvantage: You do not have best performance. To get this you need to target all possible platforms with an own OpenCL kernel.

Comment: In my case I think almost any GPU will have enough speed, but I guess customization will always get more out of bare metal--same as in CPUs, actually. Thanks!

Comment: Is this because OpenCL for CPU's does not support MMX and SSE?